# How do I turn off disks with systemd?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, suspend, systemd

I have several Ubuntu machines with both a SSD and a traditional hard disk, where the hard disk is used only occasionally.

For reasons of reducing noise, heat, and power consumption, and extending the hard disk's lifetime, I'd like to turn it off on every boot, and wake it up only when needed.

`hdparm -y` (or `-Y`) works pretty well on the command line and does exactly what I want.

But writing a systemd service to execute `hdparm` does not work. To be more precise: It works, and the disk really goes to sleep (as debugging shows), but it is immediately woken up again (and remains awake), because there's something on the system which does access the hard disks (and thus wake it) at the very end of the systemd boot process.

So how can I put a `hdparm -y` in the boot process late enough that it is not followed by any other process anymore.

My last guess would be to change systemd's default target from graphical to a new one (sleepydisks), which then depends on the former graphical target.

But isn't there an easier and plainer way to turn disks off?

Regards

Comment: Maybe there's a process that wants/needs to write to the HDD that's causing it to wake. In `terminal` type `lsof` and look for open files on the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Open the disks utility and set the drive to automatically spin down after 10 minutes of inactivity.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following script to "force" idle disks to spindown, where by force I mean a direct instruction to the drive as many WD drives are problematic with self-spindown. Perhaps you can extend this to your needs. The script is well commented so you should be able to modify it quite easily. I call it from `cron` every 20 minutes, adjust as necessary:

`spindown.sh`

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

logger "[SPINDOWN] Checking disk activity and spinning down idles..."

# Exit during maintenance
if pgrep snapraid > /dev/null; then
    logger "[SPINDOWN] Detected snapRAID maintenance. Exiting.";
    exit 0
fi

# Specify any drives you want to ignore; separate multiple drives by spaces; e.g. "sda sdb"
IGNORE_DRIVES=""

PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

# Check for idle disks and spin them down unless smartd is running tests

# Create a file on the ramdisk and cycle it to test for disk activity
(   if [ ! -f /dev/shm/diskstats_1 ]; then 
        logger "[SPINDOWN] Creating initial state file on ramdisk";
        touch /dev/shm/diskstats_1;
    fi ; 
    logger "[SPINDOWN] Updating state files on ramdisk";
    mv /dev/shm/diskstats_1 /dev/shm/diskstats_2; 
    cat /proc/diskstats > /dev/shm/diskstats_1 ) > /dev/null 2>&1

# Find all removable USB drives, so we can ignore them later,
# see http://superuser.com/a/465953
REMOVABLE_DRIVES=""
for _device in /sys/block/*/device; do
    if echo $(readlink -f "$_device")|egrep -q "usb"; then
        _disk=$(echo "$_device" | cut -f4 -d/)
        REMOVABLE_DRIVES="$REMOVABLE_DRIVES $_disk"
    fi
done

# Append detected removable drives to manually ignored drives
IGNORE_DRIVES="$IGNORE_DRIVES $REMOVABLE_DRIVES"

# Loop through all the array disks and spin down the idle disks. Will find all drives sda > sdz AND sdaa > sdaz...
logger "[SPINDOWN] Looping through drives to detect idle state"
for disk in `find /dev/ -regex '/dev/sd[a-z]+' | cut -d/ -f3`
do
    # Skip removable USB drives and those the user wants to ignore
    if [[ $IGNORE_DRIVES =~ $disk ]]; then
        continue
    fi

    # Skip SSDs
    if [[ $(cat /sys/block/$disk/queue/rotational) -eq 0 ]]; then
        continue
    fi

    # Check if drive exists
    if [ -e /dev/$disk ]; then
        logger "[SPINDOWN] Checking drive $disk"
        # Check if drive is currently spinning
        if [ "$(smartctl -i -n standby /dev/$disk | grep "ACTIVE or IDLE")" ]; then
            logger "[SPINDOWN] Disk $disk is ACTIVE or IDLE. Checking for selftest"
            # Check if smartctl is currently not running a self test
            if [ $(smartctl -a /dev/$disk | grep -c "Self-test routine in progress") = 0 ]; then
            logger "[SPINDOWN] Disk $disk is not running a self test. Checking activity."
                # Check if drive has been non idle since last run
                if [ "$(diff /dev/shm/diskstats_1 /dev/shm/diskstats_2 | grep $disk )" = "" ]; then
                    logger "[SPINDOWN] Spinning down /dev/$disk `df -h | grep /dev/$disk | rev | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | rev`"
                    hdparm -y /dev/$disk
                fi
            else
                logger "[SPINDOWN] /dev/$disk is running Self-test routine. Skipping."
            fi
        fi
    fi
done
```

As per the specific question, how to do it with systemd? ... create a timer file that calls this script (Ref: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers)

Answer (score 0):

Use the -S option of hdparm. This sets the spin down timeout, which is supposed to be maintained by the drive.

```
$ hdparm --help
-S   Set standby (spindown) timeout

$ hdparm -S 60 /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd:
 setting standby to 60 (5 minutes)
```

Do note that this is an upper-case 'S'.